# Token Based Logout - Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, token, access-token

For Logout function what Request should be Pass ? ( Access Token or any User Details?)
API Route

```
 Route::group([
      'middleware' => 'auth:api'
    ], function() {
        Route::post('logout', 'api\LoginController@logout');
    });
```

Controller function

```
public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $request->user()->token()->revoke();
        return $this->loggedOut($request);
    }
```

Comment: There are no logout functionality for API. you get access token and revoke access token. When you revoke access token user have to get access token again for call API

Comment: @Samiul Logout must be there right ? Token can remove from table na ?

Comment: No, Token not remove from table. its change revoke flag true. which mean user can't api with that token.

Comment: ya. I got it. thanks @SamiulAminShanto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send just your Access Token to request. As midleware knows that given token belong to which user.

Postman request example:

[image: screenshot postman request example]